# How do I send a digest auth request using curl?

Tags: router, authentication, curl, xml, digest

While searching for a guide I found this example on Wikipedia

```
GET /dir/index.html HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
Authorization: Digest username="Mufasa", realm="testrealm@host.com", nonce="dcd98b7102dd2f0e8b11d0f600bfb0c093", uri="/dir/index.html",
qop=auth,
nc=00000001,
cnonce="0a4f113b",
response="6629fae49393a05397450978507c4ef1",
opaque="5ccc069c403ebaf9f0171e9517f40e41"
```

(it would be great if there is a tool/site that converts requests from this form raw requests to curl command)

this the realm and nonce when I try to send a normal get request to the site.

```
 WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="device1",nonce="3c5d8f92f03d9f1afd5dd55a7b172ee8", qop="auth", algorithm="MD5"
```

[the response but from a network capture screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKo0C.png)

After searching online again for a little bit I got that the command should be like this

```
curl "url" --digest -u {username}:{pass} -vv -d @4.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"
```

but I didn't get where to put the nonce or the realm or the qop or algorithm="MD5"

while the .xml file contain the post data (in my case it's a soap action)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> You don't have to specify all those values anywhere. The only thing
> you do have to is username/password pair. CURL takes care of computing
> the client response for you. This is exactly what "supporting of
> digest authentication" means for any client.

answer by user [Alexey R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8343843/alexey-r) from stack over flow

in addition by a user on another site the command should look like this

```
curl -v  'https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/Digest/' --digest -u guest:guest --form data=blahblah
```

Comment: Instead of `digest` you can use `anyauth` I think.

Comment: @Timo yeah both works but anyauth sends two requests instead of one to check for info first

Answer (score 1):

When using Digest authentication, you need to send an HTTP "Authorization" header, and this header is where the nonce etc should go.

However, Digest uses a challenge/response mechanism that requires the Authorization header to be sent in a second HTTP request, rather than in the original HTTP request.

The second HTTP request can only be sent once the original HTTP request has received a 401 response.

You should be able to get the idea from [this closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/3385) where it's explained further about the way curl works with this.

Comment: nope this issue have nothing to do with my problem but i figured it out anyway.

Comment: hey @minanageh that's cool, why don't you post an answer with what the solution was in your case. It will help others with that problem in the future.

Comment: ok...................done